# Xcode 3.2.1 crashes on startup on OS X 10.6.2

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, xcode3.2

I have uninstalled it via the devtools uninstall command and reinstalled 3 times to no avail.  This all started when I downloaded `iphone_sdk_3.1.3_with_xcode_3.2.1__snow_leopard__10m2003a.dmg` from the DEV portal and installed.

I've trashed my com.apple.xcode.plist file, uninstalled all xcode plugins as well as Growlcode and I still can't solve this.

Here is the error information:

```
Process:         Xcode [1096]
Path:            /Developer/Developer Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.Xcode
Version:         3.1.2 (1149)
Build Info:      DevToolsIDE-11490000~1
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [196]

Date/Time:       2010-02-22 21:03:05.858 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.2 (10C540)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          373328 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           17
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  305 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   17
Anonymous UUID:                      2F82DA63-66A6-4C25-9C69-C2D02627B388

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc[1096]: garbage collection is ON
objc[1096]: layout_bitmap_or: layout bitmap too short: PBXJavaParentDV

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x96a5d43e _objc_fatal + 95
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x96a5dacf layout_bitmap_or + 91
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x96a5158c really_connect_class + 243
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x96a5137a connect_class + 254
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x96a5131f connect_class + 163
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x96a4fd67 _read_images + 1303
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x96a65933 map_images_nolock + 1545
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x96a4f0d9 map_images + 72
8   dyld                            0x8fe03f2d dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) + 795
9   dyld                            0x8fe0decd ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 251
10  dyld                            0x8fe056af dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 137
11  dyld                            0x8fe0b242 dlopen + 471
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x92b3f048 dlopen + 66
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x94937109 _CFBundleDlfcnLoadBundle + 233
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x94936c7a _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 1370
15  com.apple.Foundation            0x90c342df _NSBundleLoadCode + 995
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x90c33a67 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 820
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x90c3372d -[NSBundle load] + 42
18  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000976e4 -[XCPluginManager loadPluginBundle:] + 516
19  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00092ad2 -[XCPluginManager findAndLoadPluginsInDomain:] + 1522
20  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000924cd -[XCPluginManager findAndLoadPlugins] + 45
21  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0008c6b9 XCInitializeCoreIfNeeded + 4441
22  com.apple.Xcode                 0x00003252 0x1000 + 8786
23  com.apple.Foundation            0x90c031c7 _nsnote_callback + 176
24  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x949309a9 __CFXNotificationPost + 905
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x949303da _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
26  com.apple.Foundation            0x90bf8094 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 128
27  com.apple.Foundation            0x90c05471 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 56
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x95cc87bd -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 493
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x95cc81b9 -[NSApplication run] + 79
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x95cc0535 NSApplicationMain + 574
31  com.apple.Xcode                 0x00002bca 0x1000 + 7114
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the first argument to `dlopen`.  This probably points to a corrupted file.  You can do this with `gdb`.

```
$ gdb /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
(gdb) run
... program will hopefully crash ...
(gdb) bt
(gdb) f N                [where N is the highest numbered 'dlopen' frame]
(gdb) p (char *)*($esp)  [I think... can't test now, I'm on PPC]
```

Comment: K so it works from the command line but not when I launch it from Spotlight or the Dock, any clue on how to fix this.

Comment: Get a core dump from the crash.  Then you can load the core dump into gdb, and examine it using the same commands above.

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped me determine the issue.  The exact problem was that I had a previous version (3 versions ago) of XCode installed in /Developer/Developer Applications that I had never used.  For some reason when I installed the new version the old one came up as the top hit in Spotlight which has never happened.  Your suggestion to try from the command line lead me to the solution, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Also in looking at my error details I should have also notice Version: 3.1.2 (1149), its so similar to 3.2.1 and I was also not even thinking that it could possibly be loading the wrong one