# Xcode5 quit unexpectedly

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I am facing issue to launch `Xcode 5.1` Build version `5B130a`
before Post this question I have gone maximum issue already posted in this forum.

I followed few solution

1. Installed new `Xcode` form App Store more than 2 times
2. Download new `xcode_5.1.dmg` and install it.
3. Removed Caches and Preferences as mentioned in : ["Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the GLKit plug-in"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819058/xcode-quit-unexpectedly-while-using-the-glkit-plug-in)
4. Used **gdb** as mentioned in answer [XCode 3.2.1 crashes on startup on OSX 10.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316068/xcode-3-2-1-crashes-on-startup-on-osx-10-6-2)

   ```
   User-MacBook:~ User$ gdb /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
   GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1824) (Wed Feb  6 22:51:23 UTC 2013)
   Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
   welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
   Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
   There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
   This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin"...Reading symbols for shared libraries ...... done

   (gdb) -e
   Undefined command: "-e".  Try "help".
   (gdb) -s
   Undefined command: "-s".  Try "help".
   (gdb) run
   Starting program: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode 
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   Reading symbols for shared libraries +....++++................................................................................................................................................................................................................. done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   Reading symbols for shared libraries .... done
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   Reading symbols for shared libraries .... done
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries .... done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries ..... done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries ...... done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   2014-04-08 10:56:01.948 Xcode[1155:1603]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file://localhost/Users/Glam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%205.1.db).
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   Reading symbols for shared libraries ......... done
   warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
   Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries warning: Could not find object file "/Users/Glam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClangFormat-gtoosagpqhsosbewemdtdfqrwhvr/Build/Intermediates/ClangFormat.build/Debug/ClangFormat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TRVSClangFormat.o" - no debug information available for "TRVSClangFormat.m".

   warning: Could not find object file "/Users/Glam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClangFormat-gtoosagpqhsosbewemdtdfqrwhvr/Build/Intermediates/ClangFormat.build/Debug/ClangFormat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TRVSCodeFragment.o" - no debug information available for "TRVSCodeFragment.m".

   warning: Could not find object file "/Users/Glam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClangFormat-gtoosagpqhsosbewemdtdfqrwhvr/Build/Intermediates/ClangFormat.build/Debug/ClangFormat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TRVSFormatter.o" - no debug information available for "TRVSFormatter.m".

   warning: Could not find object file "/Users/Glam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClangFormat-gtoosagpqhsosbewemdtdfqrwhvr/Build/Intermediates/ClangFormat.build/Debug/ClangFormat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NSDocument+TRVSClangFormat.o" - no debug information available for "NSDocument+TRVSClangFormat.m".

   warning: Could not find object file "/Users/Glam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClangFormat-gtoosagpqhsosbewemdtdfqrwhvr/Build/Intermediates/ClangFormat.build/Debug/ClangFormat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TRVSXcode.o" - no debug information available for "TRVSXcode.m".

   warning: Could not find object file "/Users/Glam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClangFormat-gtoosagpqhsosbewemdtdfqrwhvr/Build/Intermediates/ClangFormat.build/Debug/ClangFormat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TRVSPreferences.o" - no debug information available for "TRVSPreferences.m".

   . done
   Reading symbols for shared libraries . done

   Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
   Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000018
   0x00007fff957b1498 in objc_msgSend_vtable3 ()
   (gdb) next
   Single stepping until exit from function objc_msgSend_vtable3, 
   which has no line number information.

   Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
   Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000018
   0x00007fff957b1498 in objc_msgSend_vtable3 ()
   (gdb)
   ```

I think this **ClangFormat.build/Debug/ClangFormat.build** is issue, since i have tried to install Clangformat project https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode. follows steps given in ReadMe file.

5. To uninstall Xcode used command

> sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

When try to launch application I get [image: alet message]

After selecting "Don't open" or "Reopen" I get "Xcode quit unexpectedly" window this contains log as shown in attached image [image: Second alert]

Please help me for fix this issue.

Comment: You mention Xcode 5 and `/Developer/...` in the same question?!?  I don't understand.

Comment: I do not get what you mean Xcode5 and /Developer/...

Comment: There is no `/Developer` with Xcode 4 or 5, and it's not clear what your question is.  Is it the use of ClangFormat with Xcode?

Comment: Question is "Xcode could not launch". Yes your right as now `uninstall-devtools` not in `/Developer/Libarary`. I have tried to install ClangFormat. Do not know Xcode check ClangFormat.